# Check if img-src exists with angular

Tags: angularjs, html

I want a simple determination if the image source exists or not, so that I can replace the image with a default image. Best case would be if this would be possible in pure html maybe with "ng-if" or something like this.

```
<img ng-if="../images/{{id}}.png"  src="../images/{{id}}.png">
```

This code obviously doesn't work, but I think it shows what I want.

EDIT:

New Code I got, which could work in my opinion, but doesn't work:

```
<img ng-src='{{ "../images/{{id}}.png" || "../images/img.png" }}'/>
```

Debugger says something about wrong quotes in this case.

EDIT:

I think the second solution works, there is just some bug in this part:

```
<img ng-src='{{"../images/{{id}}.png"}}'/>
```

This part works:

```
<img ng-src='{{"../images/img.png"}}'/>
```

Comment: whats not working ? are the images not present or can you make a fiddle

Comment: The Expression doesn't work, it doesn't show the image if the image is present neither if it isn't present. I try to create a fiddle but I'm not sure how that works with angular

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use onerror, here is a demo.

```
<img ng-src="http://experenzia.com/images/431f5cfa87f2faf9317ccc89e980dcca/431f5cfa87f2faf9317ccc89e980dcca_t.jpg" onerror="this.src='http://www.experenzia.com/assets/images/planner/no-image-back.png'" alt="" >
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted it as easy as possible, so this is the best solution for me. Maybe for some others the other solution with the directive is the best :)

Comment: https://www.caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_onerror - says this is deprecated. This also doesn't work for IE11 (important if you have to provide commercial support for it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366589/458321 - best practice is to set this up in a script, not as an attribute. The attribute is deprecated, not the event.