# What should I use instead of the deprecated `onerror` attribute?

Tags: image, error-handling, placeholder, fallback

On my images I'm setting the `onerror` attribute so that a placeholder is used in case the image is not available for some reason:

```
<img
    class="article-img"
    src="path-to-image.jpg"
    alt="some description"
    onerror="this.src='/images/fallback.png'"
>
```

Now, it looks like `onerror` [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Browser_compatibility), but I couldn't find any good source on what would be the suggested alternative way of handling the error (possibly in a similarly compact fashion).

It would be also interesting to know why it was deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

I think that was a mistake.

WHATWG still mention `onerror` in their [HTML living standard specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element:event-error).

Also, `onerror` attribute on `img` elements is not included in their [obsolete features list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features).

Comment: Would still be nice to know an alternative to support IE (need to support for commercial...otherwise I know)

Answer (score 7):

According to MDN, it seems to be deprecated as an img tag attribute but not as a global event; GlobalEventHandlers.onerror is still valid, and seemingly, they haven't classified the tag attribute event as deprecated there (in that section) yet, they're still showing an img attribute example.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

So you can still use it, but just don't use it as a tag attribute, you can place it inside a script tag or a separate file.

By the way I've just tested an img tag with an onerror attribute on the w3c validator and it's not marking it as error neither as a warning.

Comment: I get IDE warnings in JetBrains software for using it as an attribute, fwiw.

Comment: Looked everywhere but can't see why the img element's onerror attribute was marked deprecated in the MDN with [this commit](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/commit/061483ac41d43acbe9536807dd8be070c9eb031a) in 2017, and unfortunately the change author didn't say.  I've been all through the HTML specs, but I don't see what this was based on.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will ignore the onerror attribute if you put the value directly, like this:

```
<img src="yourimg.jpg" onerrror="error.png" />
```

To get around this, use a little JS in the value

```
<img src="yourimg.jpg" onerrror="this.src='error.png'" />
```