# Error handling for missing image in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, error-handling

I have an Angular 9 application. I need to display alternative image if the one specified in *src* is missing. I don't want use **onerror**, because it is deprecated.

Here is what I found:

```
<div *ngFor="let entity of entities">
  <div>
    <img [src]="entity.imageUrl" (error)="onImageError(entity)" width="70" alt="IMAGE"/>
```

How can I rewrite *entity.imageUrl* inside *onImageError()* ?

I have tried following:

```
  onImageError(entity: IEntity) {
    entity.imageUrl = 'some-image.svg'
  }
```

But it says

> 36:3  error  expected call-signature: 'onImageError' to have a
> typedef (tslint:typedef)  @typescript-eslint/tslint/config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your error is due to some typescript settings.

I would suggest you to either change the value inline like

```
(error)="entity.imageUrl = 'some-image.svg'"
```

or define the return type on the function as void

```
onImageError(entity: IEntity):void {
    entity.imageUrl = 'some-image.svg'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is now deprecated, what I already stated in original question (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979955/what-should-i-use-instead-of-the-deprecated-onerror-attribute). No onerror please

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that, I have updated my code to just what you did and it worked. probably your error is due to some typescript settings. I would suggest you to either change the value inline like '(error)="entity.imageUrl = 'some-image.svg'" or define return type on the function as void 'onImageError():void'. hope this helps

Comment: That is exactly the point, for ts 2.7 (or whatever is in newest angular) onerror is deprecated and all previous advices on stack overflow are related to earlier versions. I will check your suggestion from comment and report results here shortly.

Answer (score 2):

The property bindings are TS expressions. You could you in theory simply say

```html
<img [src]="entity?.imageUrl || alternateUrl" width="70" alt="IMAGE"/>
```

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work unfortunately. The thing is that entity.imageUrl is required field, but there might be some invalid url or url pointing to non-existing image